# Normal map baking creates distorted normal

Tags: texturing, normals, baking

I have spent quite a while working on a baking a normal map from a high poly model onto a low poly model, and the result every time regardless of how I unwrap the low poly model is always severely distorted and tends to be squashed or smaller than the actual uv itself.

Here are some screenshots of the models and the result.

[image: Image of high poly and low poly with distorted/incorrect normal map product]

Assistance is much appreciated, as always and thanks in advanced :D

Comment: To bake normalmaps the models need to lie exaxtly on top of each other.

Comment: aw thanks a tonne, the tutorial I used didn't cover that -_-.

Answer (score 2):

For people who are having trouble with this, the solution is to make sure the models are directly on top of each other.

Comment: baking normals is not calculating the difference of shapes but the distance between surface points of low and hi-poly meshes so the same points of the different surfaces need to be as close as possible.