# Blender cycles normal map not generated correctly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, baking

I'm really, really new to Blender and 3D in general, so I apologise in advance if this is a silly question.

I've created a high poly model, and a low poly version.  Then using Cycles, I've baked a normal map onto the low poly model, however, as the picture shows, something isn't right.

[image]

I've done some reading, but I can't quite understand what the problem is here.  If anyone could offer some advice or input, I'd greatly appreciate it.

After advice from Bithur, I've added a Ray Distance to the map, from .5 to 1 and it's still not working, it looks better, but still not right.  As this picture shows.

[image]

Comment: try baking with a cage and see if that helps.

Comment: also according to [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23769/normal-map-baking-creates-distorted-normal?rq=1) question the models have to be on top of each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make and apply a Normal Map?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51878/how-do-i-make-and-apply-a-normal-map) Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38555/normal-map-looking-weird-on-mesh?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Add some ray distance to your baking, it will use the "inside" of your mesh.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Any recommendations on how much of a distance to add?  I've tried it with 1 and .5 and I'm getting different, more odd results.

Comment: It depends on your scene, objects size,... You have to test to be sure but you can use orthographic views to guess how many blender units (or meters) you need with the grid.